# Difficulty in understanding a sentence said by Mr. Einstein

Tags: sentence-meaning

I am unable to understand the meaning behind the sentence: "Einstein adds: “I noticed how little difference there is between men and women; I don’t understand what kind of fatal attraction Chinese women possess which enthralls the corresponding men to such an extent that they are incapable of defending themselves against the formidable blessing of offspring.” ".

Specifically, I don't get the meaning of "formidable blessing of offspring"?
Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's partly ironic. He is referring to having children as a blessing, but in qualifying that with "formidable", he is implying that it is also a challenge. Adding in the idea of "defending themselves", he is suggesting that having children is a "blessing" that Chinese women force upon their husbands, and their husbands are so besotted with them that they let this happen.